# should i open db connection for every thread?

Tags: python, postgresql, webserver

I have developing kind of chat app. 
There are python&postgresql in server side, and xcode, android(java) side are client side(Web will be next phase).

Server program is always runing on ubuntu linux. and I create thread for every client connection in server(server program developed by python). I didnt decide how should be db operations?.

1. Should i create general DB connection and i should use this
   connection for every client's DB
   operation(Insert,update,delete..etc). In that case If i create
   general connection, I guess i got some lock issue in future. (When i try to get chat message list while other user inserting)
2. IF I create DB connection when each client connected to my server. In that case, Is there too many connection. and it gaves me performance issue in future.
3. If i create DB connection on before each db operation, then there is so much db connection open and close operation.

Whats your opinion? Whats the best way?

Comment: By general DB connection, do you mean by connection pooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to maintain a pool of database connections in the server side.

For each request, use the available connection from the pool to do database operations and release it back to the pool once you're done.

This way you will not be creating new db connections for each request, which would be a costly operation.